# Why am I receiving a DNS look-up error when requesting a web page from an AWS Windows server?

Tags: dns, amazon-ec2, amazon-aws

I installed an aspx website on a AWS EC2 windows server 12 R2 instance. Although the site works on localhost, I receive a DNS look-up failure after Chrome's timeout is reached.

I have opened inbound ports for http and am https and am obviously able to connect to connect using Desktop Connection. The server's firewall is set to accept port 80 (and 334) inbound traffic.

A dnslookup doesn't report any issues. I did see the message: instance-data:http     CLOSE_WAIT
but I have tried some many test, I don't remember where the message was issued.

I would guess there is a simple solution, but I am not a Windows Server of networking expert, so I'd welcome any suggestions on how I can resolve this issue.

Comment: By "site works on localhost," do you mean it loads using the actual domain name, or using http://localhost? Also, you probably want port 443 rather than 334 - maybe just a typo? A DNS failure wouldn't have anything to do with that though. If you try to ping the domain name remotely, does it give you an IP address? Note that it doesn't matter if ICMP is blocked, ping should still resolve the name.

Comment: I echo what dartonw is saying. It sounds like you are not properly resolving the domain name to an IP address. Check this by doing a nslookup example.com.

Comment: Even if I use the public IP address, I get the same error message.

Comment: When I ping from the Windows Sever, the DNS is resolved. When I ping from my local machine, it times out. When I open IE on the remote Windows Server and enter the domain name, I get a similar error message. The site will only come up using "localhost"

Answer (score 1):

It turned out there was an error in the web.config file. By adding:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
```

to the

```
<system.webServer> section, I was able to pinpoint the problem and resolve it.
```

Evidently IIS 7.5 ignored the error, while 8.5 did not.